# From Independent Open Source - Software server to Protocols and Encrypting?

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, javascript, software-development

The idea is to create an app that would for an example take a standard USB or old laptop. And to turn it into a cloud that is similar to that of Google Drive. The difference would be, that instead of sending the files somewhere else or to the google center - everything is going to be within the home router - placed on the usb. What would be your software recommendations for a start? All help is greatly appreciated.

Options: If possible to make it encrypted or make it an option. Highly customize a specific distribution of open-source linux server just for this use only.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185), **[edit]** your question accordingly, and it can be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the software from [FreedomBox](https://wiki.debian.org/FreedomBox) would be interesting for you to examine, they share files locally with Samba, which can also be accessed from the outside.